# Data not getting saved to Mysql database after adding a column

Tags: php, mysql

I created a simple registration form using this **[tutorial](http://www.onlinetuting.com/registration-form-in-php-video-tutorials/)**

Since  i  added an extra column last name to the form it is not saving the data in my sql database

Here is code from my files

### **Registration.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Registration Form</title>
    </head>

<body>
<form method='post' action='registration.php'>
    <table width='400' border='5' align='center'> 
    <tr>    
        <td align='center' colspan='5'><h1>Registation Form</h1></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td align='center'>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='fname' /></td>
    </tr>


   <tr> 
        <td align='center'>Last Name:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='lname' /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>    
        <td align='center'>User Password:</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='pass' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td align='center'>Email:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='email' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
        <td colspan='5' align='center'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign Up' /></td>
    </tr>


    </table>
</form>
<center><b>Already Registered</b><br><a href='login.php'>Login Here</a></center>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("users_db");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

     $user_fname = $_POST['fname'];
     $user_lname = $_POST['lname'];

     $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
     $user_email = $_POST['email'];

    if($user_fname==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your first name!')</script>";
    exit();
    }

    if($user_lname==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your last name!')</script>";
    exit();
    }

    if($user_pass==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your password!')</script>";
    exit();
    }

    if($user_email==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email!')</script>";
    exit();
    }

    $check_email = "select * from users where user_email='$user_email'";

    $run = mysql_query($check_email);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

    echo "<script>alert('Email $user_email is already exist in our database, plz try another one!')</script>";
    exit();
    }

    $query = "insert into users (user_fname,user_lname,user_pass,user_email) values ('$user_fname','$user_lname',$user_pass','$user_email')";
    if(mysql_query($query)){

    echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";

    }       
}

?>
```

When i run SHOW COLUMNS FROM users this is the output

```
Field
Type
Null
Key
Default
Extra
id
int(10)
NO
PRI
NULL
auto_increment
user_fname
varchar(100)
NO
NULL
user_lname
varchar(100)
NO
NULL
user_pass
varchar(50)
NO
NULL
user_email
varchar(100)
NO
NULL
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: Have you add that column in mysql table too?

Comment: So previous to addition of last name field in the form was the data getting saved in Database if yes than check whether you have added the column corresponding to lastname in DB

Comment: Please show a minimal code (js is not relevant in the problem for example), and show us your database.

Comment: Just for info, using PDO libraries would be better. Mysql_query is deprecated if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: run this query `'SHOW COLUMNS FROM users'` and post the output here

Comment: I have added the column to the mysql table too .I dont get any error .When i make inputs in the registration form they dont get saved as when i lookup in my sql database i dont see that input

Comment: Andrew: I updated the post with the ouput of 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM users'

Answer (score 0):

I have created insert record for you. try this also change db settings. this also goes to thanks.php to show thank you or successfull.

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_localhost2 = "localhost";
$database_localhost2 = "users_db";
$username_localhost2 = "username";
$password_localhost2 = "password";
$localhost2 = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost2, $username_localhost2, $password_localhost2) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (id, user_fname, user_lname, user_pass, user_email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_fname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_lname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_pass'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_email'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_localhost2, $localhost2);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost2) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "Thanks.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Id:</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">User_fname:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_fname" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">User_lname:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_lname" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">User_pass:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_pass" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">User_email:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_email" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the name of the database tale is 'users'. whichnames should i check against it ?

Comment: Change this: mysql_select_db("users_db"); to
mysql_select_db("users");

Comment: o and move the php to the top of the page.

Comment: the issue as that the headers cant be sent out because the php is not on top so it will not insert into database. the php must be on top for this to send out the request.

Comment: Also rather include a connections file like so on the first line of php 

<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>

including this is easier than to add connection on each page

Comment: the name of the database is users_db and the name of the table is users .changing users_db to users is helpful ?

Comment: If i move php to top of the page the form disppaers

Comment: Ok you are correct, just move the php to the top of the html and it will work due that the headers does not get send out because html is send first.

Comment: Ok test this one and see.

Comment: also you must make password store as md5 or higher. i can add it for you.

Comment: if you require simple login system where users register etc use this http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/php_login_code.htm

Comment: It gives me an error "No database elected " after submitting the form

Comment: just include <?php require_once('Connections/localhost2.php'); ?>,

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/6y70v0953/Capture.png database structure i created my side